# X people line up to get into Y different clubs.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I have a combinatorics problem, and I don't know my answer is correct or not.

The problem is the following :

Assume that X people line up to get into Y different clubs. How many ways are there to do it? (The people are distinguishable and the order people are in line matters.)

My attempt : we have Y different kinds of clubs. So, we have ${X+Y-1 \choose X}$. But, $X$ people are distinguishable, we have to permute them, $X!$. Thus, the final answer is $X!{X+Y-1 \choose X}$. Is that right answer?

Comment: No club is worth lining up for.

Comment: @wolfies What do you mean?

Comment: @user366855 That was a joke by wolfies, who apparently doesn't enjoy clubbing. Anyway, first thing that I'd point out is that to sort the people into clubs, you'd want $X+Y-1$ choose $Y-1$, because between each club is where you have your walls partitioning the people.

Comment: I'm still confused about your explanation. Why should I choose Y - 1 instead of X? Could you explain it in detail?

Comment: I think that it is the same X+Y-1 choose Y-1 as x+y-1 choose x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was initially skeptical of your answer, but eventually I arrived at the same thing.  I got there from the other direction, though.

First, set aside the clubs for a moment.  There are $X!$ ways to arrange the punters in a single queue.  Now take one of those arrangements. We need to apportion them so that in front of one club there's one, maybe; in front of another, there are none; in front of a third, there are three; etc. Basically, we have $X$ indistinguishable — right? we've fixed our arrangement for the moment — people to distribute among $Y$ distinguishable containers, and this can be done $\left(\!\!\left(Y\atop X\right)\!\!\right) = \binom{Y+X-1}{X}$ ways.

So we can line everyone up $X!\binom{Y+X-1}{X}$ ways.

Answer (score 0):

Lets consider a specific example:

We have three people: Alan, Bob and Chris
We have four Clubs Disco Stu's, Eddie's Bar, Flamingo's and Gary's Gogo.

Now if we assume each person is free to choose which club they go to and they choose in the order given

Alan, Bob and Chris each have a choice of 4 clubs so that's $4 \times 4 \times 4 =64 $ ways they can choose but we care about the order so how many ways can you order 3 people.

Making Any of 3 people can choose first any of the remaining two can choose next and finally there is only one person left to choose making $3 \times 2 \times 1 = 6$ ways So we have $6 \times 64 = 384 $ possible ways to solve this

Extracting this to the general case with $ x $ people and $ y $ clubs we have:

$$x! \cdot y^x$$

Possible ways to choose, if we care about order and who goes where.

Comment: Do you need to order Alan, Bob and Chris if each chooses a different club?

Comment: @dmk that's how I am reading the question.  If the questioner is only interested in the order they each go into a particular pub and does not care if Alan goes into Eddies Bar before Bob goes to Disco Stu's or Bob goes to the club first the question needs clarifying. It may only be important that Bob is in Disco Stu's on his own while both Alan and Chris are at Eddies and we care if Chris followed Alan in or Alan followed Chris

Comment: I see. I interpreted the question another way:  OP asked how may ways there are "to line up", so I figured he/she meant just the arrangements out in front, not how they come in. I agree that your solution matches your interpretation, though.